# redux-firebase signInWithEmailAndPassword doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-redux, firebase-authentication, react-redux-firebase

I've done all the setup for redux and redux-firebase, but when I call the signIn and signUp functions I receive only the first log (console.log(called signIn/signUp)) and not the second log  so it doesn't enter the return and I don't understand why.

this is Index:

```
    import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import rootReducer from "./store/reducers/rootReducer";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { getFirebase, ReactReduxFirebaseProvider } from "react-redux-firebase";
import firebase from "./config/firebaseConfig";
import { createFirestoreInstance } from "redux-firestore";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { isLoaded } from "react-redux-firebase";

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({ getFirebase }))
);

const rrfProps = {
  firebase,
  config: {},
  dispatch: store.dispatch,
  createFirestoreInstance,
};

function AuthIsLoaded({ children }) {
  const auth = useSelector(state => state.firebase.auth);
  if (!isLoaded(auth))
    return (
      <div className="text-center">
        <div
          className="spinner-grow text-primary"
          style={{ width: "7rem", height: "7rem" }}
          role="status"
        >
          <span className="sr-only">Loading...</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  return children;
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ReactReduxFirebaseProvider {...rrfProps}>
      <AuthIsLoaded>
      <App />
      </AuthIsLoaded>
    </ReactReduxFirebaseProvider>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

this is the reducer:

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { firebaseReducer } from "react-redux-firebase";
import { firestoreReducer } from "redux-firestore";
import authReducer from "./authReducer";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  firebase: firebaseReducer,
  firestore: firestoreReducer,
  auth: authReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

this is authReducer:

```
import { toast } from "react-toastify";

const authReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SIGN_IN":
      toast("Welcome back..");
      return state;
    case "SIGN_IN_ERR":
      toast.error("Sign in error...");
      return state;
    case "SIGN_OUT":
      toast("You signed out..");
      return state;
    case "SIGN_UP":
      toast("Welcome..");
      return state;
    case "SIGN_UP_ERR":
      toast.error("Sign up error...");
      return state;
    default:
      return state; 
  }
};

export default authReducer;
```

this is authAction:

```
export const signIn = creds => {
  console.log("called signin,",creds);
  return (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase }) => {
    const firebase = getFirebase();
    console.log("second log");
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(creds.email, creds.password)
      .then((user) => {
        console.log(user);
        dispatch({ type: "SIGN_IN" });
        console.log("finish signIn");
      })
      .catch(err => {
        dispatch({ type: "SIGN_IN_ERR" }, err);
        console.log("error signIn");
      });
  }; 
};

export const signOut = () => {
  console.log("called signOut");
  return (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase }) => {
    console.log("second log");
    const firebase = getFirebase();
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signOut()
      .then(() => {
        dispatch({ type: "SIGN_OUT" });
        console.log("finish signOut");
      });
  };
};

export const signUp = creds => {
  console.log("called signUp,",creds);
  return (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase }) => {
    console.log("second log");
    const firebase = getFirebase();
    firebase
      .auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(creds.email, creds.password)
      .then((user) => {
        console.log(user);
        dispatch({ type: "SIGN_UP" });
        console.log("ok signUp");
      })
      .catch(err => {
        dispatch({ type: "SIGN_UP_ERR" }, err);
        console.log("error signUp");
      });
  };
};
```

Comment: Hey..did you solve this issue..coz i am getting the same error. nothing happens when clicking the submit button.